# Using direct values in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

I'm a Rebol newb.  I'm often finding situations where for some reason an expression needs to have a value as a variable instead of "direct use."  I suspect that I'm just not using a switch or dereference operator correctly?

An example:

```
>> "hi"/1 ; doesn't work
== /1

>> x: "hi"
== "hi"
>> x/1 ; works
== #"h"
```

Any way I can make this and other examples work with "direct use?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
>> first "hi"    ;; also SECOND, THIRD, .... , NINTH
== #"h"

>> pick "hi" 1   ;; PICK var INDEX-VALUE 
== #"h"

>> x: "hi"       ;; like FIRST
>> last x
== #"i"

>> y: 2          ;; use Y as an index
>> pick x y      ;; same as pick x 2
== #"i"

>> x/:y          ;; the Yth char in X
== #"i"
```

Comment: Any reason why a variable must be used as the value of the "/" operator?

Comment: I don't want to assign a variable every time I have to perform some actions.

Comment: You don't have to assing a variable, try to use those functions: pick, select, find, first, second, ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but my understanding is that expressions with `/` marks in them are called paths, and *must* begin with a `word!` and not a literal — what you are calling a "direct value" — of any kind.

You can think of `/` as syntactic sugar for `pick` and `select` when you have a `word!` that serves as a variable. You cannot say `"foo"/bar` because `"foo"` is a `string!`, not a `word!`, but you can say `foo/bar` because `foo` is a `word!`.

Answer (score 1):

Each datatype has its own lexical representation which allows you to interact with its internal data (or not).

There is no actual path *syntax* or operator in REBOL.  This is mainly due to fact that Rebol is not an OOP language, even if it does have an Object! datatype.

You might not have noticed that the code `FOO/BAR` is not an expression at all, but rather a single data element which is actually of a `path! *datatype*`

```
>> FOO: context [BAR: "WTF!"]
>> type? first [ FOO/BAR ]
== path!
```

Only paths allow you to navigate Rebol data "literally".  This only occurs when paths are _*evaluated*_ .  In that case you will get the value which is obtained by navigating from that path.

```
>> type? do [ FOO/BAR ]
== string!
```

In Rebol, the generic datatype "accessors" are not lexical but programmatic in nature.  As Sunanda showed you, you use the various series functions to manipulate literal data directly.

this is very powerful since they can be "chained",  for example:

```
>> x: head remove back back back tail "-|_|-"
== "-||-"
```

I'll finish by giving you a teaser into more advanced path usage... path expressions!

```
>> blk: ["12" "34" "56" "78" "90" "ab" "cd" "ef"]
>> skip-size: 2
>> item: 3
>> blk/(skip-size * item - 1)/2
== #"0"
```

Note that you can really put any code in the paren! if it follows data which can be navigated.